# Delphi: How to correctly divide to a float number

Tags: delphi

First day using Delphi Community IDE, I've been able to create a calculator app. I've done mostly `Python` and `R` programming.

But I'm having trouble with the Division Operation. I've hardcoded 2 values just to make sure the operation is based on float numbers.

I would like to get `2.5` in the panel caption, when dividing 5 to 2.

```
iAns := 5 / 2.0; yields:

[dcc32 Error] hello_world.pas(189): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended'
[dcc32 Error] hello_world.pas(189): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'hello_world.pas'
```

**This is the function that does the operation based on if else conditionals:**

```
procedure TForm1.btnEqualsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
iNum2 := StrToInt(edt1.Text);
edt1.Clear;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(iNum1));
ShowMessage(IntToStr(iNum2));

if Operant = '+' then
    begin
        iAns := iNum1 + iNum2;
        pnl1.Caption :=  IntToStr(iAns);
    end
else if Operant = '-' then
    begin
        iAns := iNum1 - iNum2;
        pnl1.Caption :=  IntToStr(iAns);
    end
else if Operant = '*' then
    begin
        iAns := iNum1 * iNum2;
        pnl1.Caption :=  IntToStr(iAns);
    end
else if Operant = '/' then
    begin
        iAns := 5 / 2.0;
        pnl1.Caption :=  FloatToStr(iAns);
    end
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE 1**:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  iNum1, iNum2, iAns : Integer;
  rNum1, rNum2, rAns : Integer;
  Operant : String;
```

Comment: @J... I understand the error, but comming from other languages it wasn't clear for me the importance of the type declaration of the variable at the beggining. I think this could be useful in the future.

Comment: Contrary to what you were told in a comment below the answer, the first source of understanding basic language features and specifics, is to look at the documentation. In the help topics listed in `RAD Studio, RAD Studio Topics, Delphi reference, Delphi Language Guide` you will find the information you need and to avoid downvotes for asking too elementary questions. For example, `Language Overview`, 1st sentence, says: `Delphi is ... , strongly typed language ...` which should ring a bell to look at `Data Types, Variables and Constants`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iAns` is declared as an integer. And a variable of integer type cannot hold a non-integral value like `2.5`, which is what you get by `5 / 2.0`. You need to declare `iAns` with a floating-point type instead, like `double` (or `real`, `single`, `extended`: read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Real_Types) about these).

Some additional hints:

- `5 / 2` will work just as well as `5 / 2.0`, since the `/` operator always performs a floating-point division. You will get `2.5`.
- Delphi also has an integer division operator, `div`. `5 div 2` yields the integer `2`.

Notice how the compiler actually told you this already. It probably pointed you to the line `iAns := 5 / 2.0` telling you that `integer` (the type of `iAns`) isn't compatible with `extended` (the type of the right-hand side).

Comment: Hi, please, see update 1. Also, where can I put this basic questions? I've already 1 down vote :(

Comment: basic questions can be solved by searching in google, but better would be to just try things out, experiment, make a test project where you can try different codes and see for yourself the difference. That way you will learn more then by googling and copy/pasting solutions